# Error uso procedimiento almacenado en php

Tags: php, stored-procedure

Codigo que utiliza un procedimiento almacenado para eliminar datos de una tabla de mi base de datos. Salta un error en el bind_param y no se como solucionarlo.
Estaria agradecido si alguien le puede echar un vistazo.
El error que salta es Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\wamp64\www\Peluqueria2.0\eliminar.php on line 11.
**Código PHP:**

```
<?php 
    $db = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "", "peluqueria");
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
            echo "Falló la conexión con MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
            exit;
        }
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("QuitarCita(?, ?, ?, @salida)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $usuario, $correo, $fecha);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows!=1) {
        echo "Error al insertar";
        exit();
    }else{
        header("Location: home.html");
        exit;
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que salta? Pulsa en [edit] para agregarlo y de paso cambia las imágenes por el texto del código. Las imágenes sirven de poco para analizar el problema en este caso.

Comment: Creo que ya esta editado correctamente junto con el error que me salta. Disculpa por lo de las imagenes es la primera vez que pregunto y no lo sabia

Comment: El `->prepare` te está dando error, y te está devolviendo un booleano en lugar del stmt que esperas. Revisa el error que te da.

Comment: Tienes que usar CALL, intenta así: `$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL QuitarCita(?, ?, ?, @salida)");`

Comment: Era eso. Muchisimas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error: *`Call to a member function bind_param() on bool`* significa que el objeto que usas para llamar a `bind_param` es un booleano (bool).

En tu código ese objeto es, `$stmt` como podemos ver aquí:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $usuario, $correo, $fecha);
```

Pues bien, `$stmt` no es lo que debería ser: un objeto statement, es un booleano que equivale a `false` porque sin duda algo falló cuando lo creaste.

`$stmt` se crea aquí:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("QuitarCita(?, ?, ?, @salida)");
```

Y precisamente ahí vemos el fallo: **debes usar [`CALL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html)** para llamar a los procedimientos almacenados. Haciendo esto el problema debería corregirse:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL QuitarCita(?, ?, ?, @salida)");
```

De todos modos, te recomiendo que controles mejor tu código, tanto los datos que recibes por POST, como el flujo del mismo, verificando los posibles errores. Evita también mostrar mensajes de error internos de la base de datos, por ejemplo cuando hay errores de conexión. Esos mensajes podrían revelar información que podría ser explotada por usuarios mal intencionados.